# Right way to manage different car animation

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I have several **animated car object** which have own animation and animation control script. Car object running on road and I want to manage
 all the car animation i.e.,

1. if any car is ahead then I am slow down backward car so that it not
   collide or bypass ahead car.
2. if ahead car is stop then i am stop backward car and play and speed
   up accordingly.

I have tried raycast for this technique, I added collider to every car then, I raycast forward from every car.
 it partially working and sometime don't detect ahead object correclty as my code else statement doesn't seems right.

```
I think that it is not the right way to do this job. what is the correct way to do as Raycast is also expensive

    if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, transformForwad, out rayHit, 10f))
            {
                if (rayHit.transform.tag == "Car")
                {
                    Debug.Log("car collide,  current object: "+ transform.name +" : hitted "+ rayHit.transform.name);
                    isCarNearToAnotherCar = true;
                    ANIMATION_OBJECT.GetComponent<Animation>()[ClipName].speed = rayHit.transform.GetComponent<AnimationControlSpeed>().Speed/2;

                }
                else {
                    Debug.Log("car collide end,  current object: " + transform.name + " : hitted " + rayHit.transform.name);
                    isCarNearToAnotherCar = false;
                }

            }

//Update speed only when isCarNearToAnotherCaris false.
        if (!isCarNearToAnotherCar)
        {//normal the speed, when there is no car ahead
            ANIMATION_OBJECT.GetComponent<Animation>()[ClipName].speed = Speed;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Two options as I see:
**1)** As you control all the cars and you know their order (which as you say, never changes), why don't you just make the math based on the cars' position & dimensions, instead of raycasting? Compare the leadfoot's dimensions & position to 2nd car and act accordingly, then 2nd with 3rd, and so on.
-or, IMHO even better-
**2)** Why don't you use colliders? You can add a trigger collider to the front bumper of the cars, and trigger an event when it touches the front car's rigid body. You can place the collider as you wish to set the 'reaction range' what you like.
You can even set different "collision avoidance box" sizes for the different cars, based on how "brave" the drivers are - as of getting too close to the one riding ahead.

Comment: Thanks for your input but you questions seems complicated